# Gnuplot: Labels plotted many times

Tags: label, gnuplot

I'm doing a multiplot on `gnuplot 5.0` and I set my own labels for the `y axis`, but it seems that some of these labels are plotted more than once, since they have a bold outlook. 
Here is what it looks like:

[image: current output]

Here is my code:

```
set multiplot layout 3,2 rowsfirst title 'Time stuff'

TOPGRAPH = "set tmargin at screen 0.80;set bmargin at screen 0.60;set ytics(0,14,18,22);set yrange[12:22];unset ylabel"
MIDDLEGRAPH = "set tmargin at screen 0.60;set bmargin at screen 0.40;set ytics(0,2,5,8);set yrange[0:10];unset ylabel"
BOTTOMGRAPH = "set tmargin at screen 0.40;set bmargin at screen 0.20;set ytics(0,6,7);set yrange[5:8];unset ylabel"
LRMARGIN = "set lmargin at screen 0.15;set rmargin at screen 0.45"
NOXLABEL = "unset xlabel"
XTICS = "set xtics 0,2500,10000; set format ''"




@TOPGRAPH;@LRMARGIN;@NOXLABEL;@XTICS
set label 1 'X length' at screen 0.10, 0.65 rotate left
plot 'ite_x' u 1:3:4 w filledcu lc 'grey' notitle, 'ite_x' u 1:2 w lines lc 'red' notitle


@MIDDLEGRAPH;@LRMARGIN;@NOXLABEL;@XTICS
set label 2 'Y length' at screen 0.10,0.45 rotate left
plot 'ite_y' u 1:3:4 w filledcu lc 'grey' notitle, 'ite_y' u 1:2 w lines lc 'red' notitle

@BOTTOMGRAPH;@LRMARGIN
set arrow from 0,5 to 0,8 nohead front
set label 3 'Z length' at screen 0.10,0.25 rotate left
unset format x
set xtics 0,2500,10000
set xlabel 'Time when bead placed'
plot 'ite_z' u 1:3:4 w filledcu lc 'grey' notitle, 'ite_z' u 1:2 w lines lc 'red' notitle
```

Comment: I don't think they're plotted more than once (but I may be wrong). You could try adding a `unset label` right before your `set label` statements just to be sure.

Comment: "X length" is plotted 3 times, "Y length" is plotted twice, and "Z length" only once because you keep creating new labels rather than re-setting the previous one. You can use `set label 1` for all three commands (rather than `set label 2` and `set label 3`).

Comment: Or, after plotting each one, do an `unset label 1` before proceeding to the next one.